# Нужен ли нам Помощник для создания вопросов (Ask Question Wizard)?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, ask-question-wizard

Я что-то пропустил это дело, но в английской версии Stack Overflow более чем полгода назад [выкатили Помощник для создания вопросов (Ask Question Wizard)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381671/1991579).

Посмотреть как это выглядит можно [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Цель была в том, чтобы снизить число некачественных вопросов. На вопрос о том, [доедет ли эта штука до нас](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390863/1991579), сказали, что, если у нас есть проблема с некачественными вопросами, то можем тоже запросить.

1. Есть ли у нас такая проблема?
2. Если да, нужна ли нам эта фича?

Comment: Не вижу там ничего подобного. Эти пункты просто идут справкой справа. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jOWa.png

Comment: @Qwertiy вы олд. Визард у новых участников появляется.

Comment: По-моему было бы полезно (я не олд, у меня визард есть, хех)

Comment: @andreymal уверены, что мы про одно и то же говорим? )

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica да

Comment: @andreymal странно. Должно показываться лишь тем, у кого меньше 111 репы.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica быть может, накосячили и 100 репы за Association Bonus не учитываются?

Comment: @andreymal кто знает ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Нужен, с одним пунктом - "Вопрос следует задавать на русском языке".

Comment: Визард нужен хотя бы потому что он сразу до поля ввода показывает каким должен быть вопрос. Также он помогает понять какие вопросы приняты вв данном сообществе и не будут сразу зафлаганы и заминусованы. Типы в сайдбаре это конечно прекрасно, но вряд-ли кто-то их читает. А так сразу наглядно видно, что надо сделать чтобы задать вопрос. Возможно что общее кол-во новых вопросов уменьшится и кто-то не будет задавать "Я хочу просто задать, а не вот это все, нафиг ваши советы". Но так как большинство некачественных вопросов идет как раз от новичков (<100 репы), то будет как раз таки полезно.