# Нужна ли нам причина закрытия вопросов «учебные задания»?

Tags: обсуждение, причины-закрытия, домашки

#### История

На сколько я понимаю, впервые вопрос «работы за автора» был поднят в середине 2015 года в вопросе «[Работа за автора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/231/6)». В результате обсуждения пришли к выводу, что многие вопросы «Как сделать Х используя Y» полезные и допустимы на сайте.

В следующий раз тема рассматривалась в 2017 году: «[Допустимы ли вопросы, где подразумевается работа за автора?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4882/6)». Кратко: в контексте цели сайта — собрать базу  знаний, формат «сделайте за меня» не показатель плохого вопроса. Проблемные вопросы — те, в которых, собственно, нет конкретного прикладного вопроса.

Всё же, участники [продолжили](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4992/6) активно настаивать на добавлении причины закрытия для вопросов, подозрительно похожих на домашние задания. В результате, [была добавлена](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5043/6) новая причина закрытия «не по теме»:

> Сообщение содержит лишь текст задачи, в котором нет описания проблемы, либо вопрос чисто формален («как мне выполнить это задание»). Для повторного открытия вопроса, добавьте описание конкретной проблемы, поясните, что именно не получается, в чём вы видите проблему.

Ещё мы уточнили, что вопросы–домашние задания != вопросы, где подразумевается работа за автора.

К концу 2017 года, [модераторы показали](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6189/6), что причиной начали злоупотреблять. Как ответ на неверное использование причины закрытия вопросов, была предложена иная, действующая по сей день, формулировка:

> **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

#### Текущая ситуация

На данный момент среди участников сообщества есть идея удаления причины закрытия вопросов «учебное задание». Основной аргумент — ссылка на вопрос «[Что делать с вопросами по типу "нужно решить задачу, но сам я ничего не сделал"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9631/6)», в котором спрашивается, что делать с вопросами, которые похожи на «работу за автора» и для которых причина закрытия «учебные задания» не подходит. Наибольший отклик получил [ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9634/6), который говорит «Ничего не надо делать. Такие вопросы могут быть интересными и полезными». Другой [ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9632/6), как я понял, предлагает голосовать против подобных вопросов. Часть участников по ответам сделала вывод, что хорошим решением было бы удаление причины закрытия «учебные задания». На  мой взгляд, связь не очевидна, как результат, давайте вместе обсудим предлагаемое решение:

> Нужно ли удалять причину закрытия «учебные задания» или всё–таки она нам не мешает? Если нужно, то почему?

#### Что вы думаете?

Пожалуйста, поделитесь, какие мысли у вас есть на этот счёт?

- Используете ли вы эту причину закрытия? Как часто?
- Видите ли в ней пользу? Или она вам не нравится так сильно, что вы хотите удалить ее из списка?
- Какие плюсы и минусы вы видите в каждом из решений?

Пожалуйста, постарайтесь максимально аргументировать свои мысли в ответе. Для этого, возможно, вам будет полезно:

- Посмотреть на статистику по всем причинам закрытия [на основном сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days) (для просмотра требуется 10К репутации, поэтому [доступен экранный снимок](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlLI0.png)).
- Вручную просмотреть какое–то количество закрытых и удаленных вопросов на сайте (фильтры `closed:1`).

#### [Зачем на сайте присутствует функционал закрытия вопросов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1936/6)

На мой взгляд, принимая подобные решения, очень важно помнить, что закрытие вопросов — это инструмент сообщества, у которого есть вполне конкретное назначение. В двух словах — закрытие необходимо, чтобы оградиться от содержимого, которое мы не можем отнести к полезной базе знаний прикладных решений. Закрытие вопросов *дополняет* другие инструменты, например, голосование за или против, которое, в двух словах, необходимо для сортировки содержимого. Эти две возможности движка дополняют друг друга, но не заменяют.

Comment: Вы рассматриваете предложения ?? Может просто стоит ввести метку `домашка` либо `домашняя работа`, кто хочет решает, кто не хочет проходит мимо.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky А для `deleted:all`?

Comment: @Yaant Согласно [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), как я понимаю, тоже.

Comment: Я тут еще новичок, посему свое мнение напишу в комментарии, а не в ответе. Мне кажется, не стоит убирать эту причину закрытия. На мой взгляд она дает автору вопроса четкое понимание причины закрытия. Минусование вопроса в этом отношении на много менее наглядно. Что касается  идеи timob256 с меткой "домашка"... Возможно, это была бы неплохая идея, хотя, подозреваю, большинство ее отправят в игнор.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky То есть советом посмотреть статистику и удаленные вопросы, смогут воспользоваться только 112 пользователей сайта (из них только 90 проявляли активность в течение последнего месяца)?

Comment: @Yaant, вот раскладка по причинам закрытия за последние три месяца: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlLI0.png. Сначала идёт список причин, затем статистика.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Пожалуйста,  опубликуйте ваш комментарий ответом. Иначе он потеряется!

Comment: @Arhad-the-dev Спасибо! Не могли бы вы добавить ссылку прямо в вопрос, чтобы все могли посмотреть?

Comment: @Arhad-the-dev Ага, спасибо :)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, хорошо, опубликовал.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, добавил. Не знаю, насколько хорошо сформулировал добавленный текст, так что исправьте под стиль вопроса, если что-то не так.

Comment: Большая часть текста - вода. А про само предложение по удалению причины всего пара строк. Акцент совсем смещён, как по мне =\

Comment: @Qwertiy: прошу Вас перестать вносить изменения в первоначальную мысль автора. Оставьте пост таким, каким его видел его создатель.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov во-первых, у нас участники могут вносить правки в чужие сообщения. И это, в общем-то, даже рекомендуется и поощряется. Конкретно в случае с этой правкой, официальный ответ от мод. состава такой: мы получили комментарии от автора вопроса, он с правкой согласен. Посему, я откатываю вашу правку. Также предупреждаю вас и других участников, что правки по этому куску текста, если они продолжатся, будут расцениваться как вандализм со всеми вытекающими.

Comment: *Большая часть текста - вода. А про само предложение по удалению причины всего пара строк. Акцент совсем смещён, как по мне* — @Suvitruf, вы так говорите, как будто ожидали другого ;)

Comment: вот собственно свежий пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1043175/223826 и вопрос задан, и код приведен, но все равно упорно тыкают в "Закрыть учебное"

Comment: А почему нельзя ввести премодерацию вопросов? Делаем очередь на предварительную модерацию для тех, чей рейтинг ниже некоторого уровня, оттуда вопросы могут попасть в ленту, если их одобрит кто-то из участников с высоким рейтингом. За эту работу также назначаются баллы.

Comment: Как насчет требовать поднять цену до 50 баллов за такие вопросы?

Comment: @Zealint То есть вместо очереди проверки на закрытие ввести значительно более длинную очередь проверки на открытие? И автор будет часами и днями ждать, когда его вопрос появится в ленте? Тогда сюда новички вообще перестанут приходить с вопросами.

Answer (score 23):

Вроде как все понимают, что тащить домашки на SO - это плохо, не приветствуется сообществом, бесит профессионалов и прочее. Да, **таким вопросам не место на сайте**.

Но сейчас **для борьбы с ними выбран неправильный инструмент**.

Давайте попробуем отделить ненависть к "домашкам и халявщикам"

Что мы хотим сделать с домашками:

- Убрать их с глаз долой
- Помешать автору и дальше тащить домашнюю работу на SO
- Уменьшить количество человек, которые могут увидеть домашку и дать ответ на нее
- Обеспечить это все силами минимального количества участников

Ок, отлично. Мы почему-то решили использовать для этого механизм "требования правки". Давайте посмотрим, насколько хорошо это работает:

- Закрытые вопросы не исчезают с ленты
- Автор и дальше может задавать вопросы
- Вопрос принудительно попадает медленную забитую очередь на ревью еще пятерым участникам с высокой репутацией.
- Для закрытия нужно минимум 5 человек с 3000+ репутации. У них ограниченное количество голосов в день.
- (бонус) в интерфейсе очереди можно закрыть, но нельзя минусануть :)

Я бы сказал, работает вообще не в ту сторону, как хотелось бы.

**Ради каждого вопроса-домашки мы *собираем консилиум из пяти человек, которые всесторонне его изучают, и решают, домашка это или нет**. Даже если там явная копипаста из учебника.

Как сейчас выглядит очередь на закрытие? Вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наличие стандартной причины закрытия для домашек, и само решение использовать механизм "требования правки/закрытия для них" наносит прямой вред сайту. Вместо борьбы авторы вопросов-домашек получают дополнительное время, дополнительную рекламу и дополнительный шанс получить ответ. И ради этой рекламы, ради этого бонуса для "халявщиков-однодневок" мы тратим время постоянных участников.

Причину стоит снести, и перестать "требовать правки" у авторов вопросов-домашек. Это примерно как требовать правки спама. Просто насчет спама давно договорились, а на счет "домашки" - решили выбросить опыт enSO и "пойти своим путем".

---

Что стоит использовать для борьбы с домашками? Обычное минусование!

- Заминусованные вопросы исчезают с ленты
- Автор попадает в question ban, и не может задавать новые вопросы
- Нет в ленте, нет в очереди - никто не видит
- Достаточно троих участников с 125 репутации. При этом участники не теряют репутацию. Минусы за вопросы - бесплатны. У каждого - по 50 минусов в день.
- (бонус) участники с 10к репутации могут удалять заминусованные вопросы напрямую.

Увидел домашку, нажал минус, пошел дальше. Этого достаточно, чтобы быстро и эффективно убирать ее с сайта.

---

Именно этот подход был [принят у нас до введения причины закрытия](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/233/177221). Я до сих пор не понимаю, почему вдруг передумали, и решили еще раз наступить на грабли и начать использовать неподходящий инструмент. Обсуждения "давайте введем причину закрытия потому что '*обоснование почему именно закрытие*' на мете не было. "Сообщество требует именно закрывать, на enSO не сработало, а у нас внезапно сработает" - как-то так.

---

## Дополнительные пояснения:

#### Зачем закрываются вопросы?

> В двух словах — закрытие необходимо, чтобы оградиться от содержимого, которое мы не можем отнести к полезной базе знаний прикладных решений.

Это не совсем так. Возможно, это было так на hashcode, но это явно не так на SO. Мы не закрываем, мы "требуем правки". Это способ сказать автору вопроса:

> Для получения однозначного ответа на вопрос нужна дополнительная информация или смена формулировки, которую можешь сделать только ты, автор
>   Тема вопроса не относится к программированию или администрированию

Абсолютно бесполезно закрывать вопрос с формулировкой "мы не верим, что ты пытался решить задачу сам". Потому что это не имеет отношения к **содержимому** вопроса. Ну и опять же - закрытие - это способ **оградиться от содержимого**, а не от мотивации людей, которые это содержимое создают.

#### Связь с постом "Мне нужно решить задачу"

[Что делать с вопросами по типу "нужно решить задачу, но сам я ничего не сделал"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9631/6)

Связь, на самом деле, достаточно простая. И автор поста испытывает те же чувства к "халявщикам", но к смежной категории вопросов. Он пытается оценивать намерения автора, а не содержимое вопросов. От использования закрытия его сдерживает только слово "учебные" в формулировке. В чем разница учебного и неучебного задания? В том, что за учебное задание автор получит оценку, а **за неучебное задание автор получит зарплату**. Суть моего ответа в том вопросе - вместо того, чтобы тратить время и силы еще и на закрытие еще и неучебных заданий, стоит наоборот, перестать тратить время на закрытие учебных.

Нужно использовать подходящий инструмент для решения проблемы, а закидывать вопрос всем, что есть, не задумываясь о последствиях. :)

Comment: Позицию поддерживаю, вот только требование о минусовании вместо закрытия надо будет прописать прям в диалоге тревог, большими жирными буквами, иначе участники так и будут по незнанию кидать первые попавшиеся тревоги. Причём для этого достаточно всего лишь поправить перевод, не привлекая силы на изменение макета.

Comment: @Arhad-the-dev да, хорошая идея. Возможно стоит там же дописать, что минусы на вопросы бесплатны. Многие не минусуют потому, что жалеют -1 (когда у тебя 125 репутации - каждого минуса жалко).

Comment: Плюс / минус согласен с ответом. Правда, есть пара мыслей. Одна из задач этой причины закрытия была в снижение агрессии к новичкам: мы закрывали домашки и шли дальше. Удалив ее, вероятно: (1) увеличится количество оскорблений в комментариях; (2) будут просто закрывать с другой причиной.  Кроме того, сейчас у нас есть два инструмента: закрытие и голос против. Убрав закрытие, теоретически, у нас остается лишь один. То есть есть вероятность, что таких вопросов будет оставаться на сайте больше.

Comment: Видите ли вы какие–либо способы борьбы с агрессией против новичков?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky закрытие сокращает только время жизни заминусованного вопроса, и только с 30 до 7 дней, насколько я помню. Т.е. вопросы будут оставаться на сайте дольше, но в результате все равно будут удалены ботом. Заминусованные вопросы все равно уходят с главной, так что они будут недостижимы до большинства посетителей. Единственное опасение - кто-то будет "фармить репу" на таких вопросах - но они и сейчас могут это делать, т.к. закрытие у нас дико медленное.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky насчет агрессии - оставить злобный комментарий проще, чем закрыть. Закрытие не срабатывает мгновенно, и не снимает агрессию сразу же.  Так что оно не особо выпускает пар. Минус - применяется сразу же, у него видимый эффект. Проще донести, что минуса бесплатны - может быть люди боятся -1 потерять.

Comment: Вижу хороший аргумент в пользу того чтобы как закрывать, так и минусовать такие вопросы. Боюсь что попытка сэкономить место в очереди закрытия не сработает. Вопросы плохие и их все равно будут закрывать за отсутствие примера, либо как слишком общие или непонятные.

Comment: @defaultlocale да, но закрытие за отсутствие примера, общность или непонятность даёт автору прямое указание  - как улучшить вопрос. А не просто выбрасывает вопрос с припиской "попробуй сначала решить сам".

Comment: @PashaPash Полностью согласен что другие причины иллюстративнее. Но механизм закрытия в большинстве случаев все равно придется запускать.

Comment: Как вижу, причину закрытия убрали. Теперь как без рук - непонятно что делать с вопросами *сделайте за меня*. Вроде бы минусуешь, но как-то не информативно для вопрошающего получается.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko на сайте почти все вопросы - это "сделайте за меня". [Если вопрос требует дополнения со стороны автора -  "требуйте правки" (закрытием). Если не требует - или минусуйте, или ничего не делайте.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/233/). Поверьте, те, кто тащит домашку на ruSO знают, что ее надо решать самостоятельно и без "информативного закрытия".

Answer (score 12):

Как я уже [писал](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9634/178988) в лидирующем (+22 -2) ответе на аналогичный вопрос, сам факт того, что вопрос является домашкой, либо же что автор не продемонстрировал попытки его решить, не только не являются проблемой, но и не говорит о качестве вопроса.

Имеющаяся причина закрытия явно нацелена на домашки и её пытаются притянуть за уши туда, куда не надо, о чём явно свидетельствует сам вопрос, к которому размещён тот ответ.

**Таким образом становится понятно, что саму причину надо убрать.**

---

#### Надо ли её заменить на другую аналогичную?

Как говорится в регламенте, минимум изменений за раз. Сначала убираем причину и смотрим. Если нужна какая-то заменяющая причина, добавляем в тот момент, когда это увидим.

Со своей стороны я вполне допускаю возможность последующего добавления причины, отражающей бесполезность вопроса для базы знаний. У нас уже есть причина "Вопрос слишком общий" - в какой-то мере она применима, но с текущим описанием на домашке она будет смотреться как минимум странно. Может понадобиться что-то такое:

> Вопрос объединяет несколько атомарных независимых действий, например, математику и ввод-вывод. Возможно его стоит разбить на соответствующие атомарные вопросы, но предварительно стоит убедиться, что такие вопросы ещё не задавались, потому что в большинстве случаев вероятность существования таких вопросов достаточно велика.

На точность формулировки не претендую, она заслуживает отдельного обсуждения, если такая причина действительно понадобится, но тут я хотел отразить что:

- атомарные вопросы - это хорошие вопросы
- участник может и должен скомпановать программу сам
- должно быть понятно, что надо задачу сначала поделить, потом поискать на сайте, а затем уже, если не вышло, делить вопрос на части
- явно не удалось отразить, что сам вопрос можно превратить в одну из частей, а не забрасывать

Answer (score 9):

Сложно обсуждать такие вопросы в таком виде, т.к. слишком большая тема. И сложно всё охватить. Но попробую немного дать пищи для размышлений.

## Введение

Паша, Qwertiy и многие другие уже отвечали. С "домашками" есть проблема. И не только у нас. Об этом пишут и модераторы других сайтов сети.

Я приведу несколько примеров с других сайтов:

- Stats.SE: [раз](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1172), [два](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4393), [три](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5064), [четыре](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2685), [пять](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2843).
- Math.SE: [раз](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201/262906), [два](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/262906), [три](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14981/262906).
- Physics.SE: [раз](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7407/93246), [два](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5179/93246), [три](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7162/93246).
- CS.SE: [раз](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1151/63426), [два](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/63426), [три](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/751/63426), [четыре](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755).
- Crypto.SE: [раз](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1115/351), [два](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/90/351).
- Biology.SE: [раз (на Биологии даже отдельный пункт в справке есть)](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework), [два](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266/homework-policy-for-faq) [три](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3233/whats-better-closing-as-homework-or-adding-homework-tag), [четыре](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1847/updating-statement-on-closed-reason-for-no-work-shown).

**Примеры экспериментов:**

1. На enSO уже полгода обкатывают [Ask Question Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381671/1991579). Я бы хотел и у нас эту штуку увидеть: [Нужен ли нам Ask Question Wizard?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9692/15479)
2. Всё на том же enSO эксперимент со [снижением числа необходимых голосующих до 3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388313/1991579) (сейчас 5).

## Почему закрывают с этой причиной

По-разному:

1. Потому что ответ на такие вопросы - это медвежья услуга автору.
2. Потому что автор не пытался ничего сделать.
3. Потому что вопрос бесполезен сообществу.

Я как один из топов, так и как модератор наблюдаю за очередями. Люди очень часто закрывают по п.2, упуская, что SO - это база знаний, а не сайт помощи одному участнику. В итоге под раздачу попадают вопросы, где автор ничего сам не делал, но при этом **сам вопрос вполне хороший**.

## Причина закрытия не работает даже, если это реально плохой вопрос

1. Если это плохой вопрос, то его нужно минусовать, чтоб через 9 дней он был удалён ботом. Закрытие бесполезных вопросов лишь сбивает с толку участника.
2. Даже если вопрос можно улучшить, то часть участников просто не понимает, что делать с их вопросов после его закрытия. Многие просто уходят.

## Минусовать вместо закрытия

Шило на мыло. Если в случае с закрытием, есть хоть какое-то пояснение в причине закрытия, то при молчаливом минусовании автор вообще будь не в курсе, что не так.

## Что же делать?

Я этот вопрос обсуждал с другим модераторами (с других сайтов в том числе) и с Шогом. Мы можем провести эксперимент и отключить эту причину, скажем, на неделю. Но в таком случае нужно оценить эффект. Если посмотрим [нашу статистику по закрытиями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats), то увидим.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

26% закрытий как "непонятна суть вопроса". Если мы просто уберём причину, то что будут делать закрывашки? Предполагаю, что будут просто подгонять под другую причину. И, скорей всего, это будет "непонятная суть" или "мой код не работает".

Просто ради интереса статистика с enSO:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это больше к тому, что нужно смотреть на другие сайты, но не нужно в точности следовать их решениям, т.к. специфика и менталитет отличаются.

## Много буков, но что же делать?

1. Отключить для начала причину на неделю.
2. Сделать отдельный пост на Мете с меткой [важное](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5).
3. В посте описать кратко суть решения с ссылками нужными и, самое главное, описать, что теперь делать людям, которые усердно закрывали вопросы как "домашки". Донести мысль, что нельзя просто выбирать другую более-менее подходящую причину. Желательно убедить людей отписываться в комментариях, чтобы авторы могли поправить вопрос или чтоб донесли до авторов мысль, что это не формат SO и, вероятно, минусовать.
4. Собираем метрики. Через неделю смотрим, как это отразилось на других очередях. Как изменился процент закрытых вопросов. Если возможно оценить комментарии.
5. Сделать выводы. Либо живём без этой причины, либо возвращаем/меняем описание.

Comment: Мне 5й пункт не нравится, а именно "Либо живём без этой причины, либо возвращаем" - есть вариант менять (переформулировать) причину и он лучше, чем возвращать старую.

Comment: @Qwertiy если эксперимент провалится, то мы возвращаем причину для начала. А потом смотрим, как можно её переформулировать. Всё постепенно.

Comment: Не согласен. Имеет смысл сразу пробовать менять и смотреть снова. Возврат ничего нового не даст.

Comment: @Qwertiy но это в случае провала. Если провалится, то там по факту и решим. Но эксперимент же будет удачным, да? ٩(◕‿◕｡)۶ Вообще подправил эту часть. Особых проблем в том, чтобы поменять, не вижу.

Comment: Я пока знаю, что эта причина мне не нравится. Возможность вместо неё ввести другую я вполне допускаю. Но для начала удаляем и смотрим :)

Comment: При "Закрытии" в комент спускаются "Шаблонные" коментарии, можно ли в случае домашки предусмотреть "Шаблонный" коментарий без закрытия. Что б не сочинять каждый раз фразу "это похоже на домашку, данный сайт не для решения домашних заданий" и т.п, а для всех домашек одинаковый комент по какой-то кнопке? Тогда будет ясность, нажал княпку - уведомил, нажал минус и гуляем.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica целиком и полностью разделяю Ваше видение вопроса.

Answer (score 7):

Если убрать данную причину, то имхо задавшему вопрос не будет понимать, чем он провинился.

Как я понимаю, единственным способом отправления неугодных вопросом обратно в "ад" будет их заминусовывание.

По моему формулировка достаточно добротная и понятная:

Хочешь, что бы тебе помогли? Приложи усилия и напиши четко, что не получилось, а не просто `COPY/PASTE` из учебника, что как бы является открытым плевком в лицо сообществу.

Вот хорошо оформленный вопрос пусть даже по домашке и даже без прикладывания кода может выстрелить, если автор удосужится описать свой ход мыслей при попытках подойти к решению.

А то сейчас понабегут школьники, которым пофигу, что их вопрос заминусуют, но есть вероятность, что найдется все участник, желающий подфармить репу.

Ценность и качество у подобных вопросов около 0:

1. Помогите перевести из одного языка в другой
2. ПАСАНЫ, Я НА ЛАБЕ СРОЧНА НУЖНА ПОМОЩЬ!!!

Закрытием подобных вопросов сообщество выражает протест.

Заодно и подчищаем генофонд IT-специалистов и не оказываем медвежью услугу двоечникам, с которыми нам придется работать в будущем.

Comment: Да ладно, скопипастивший задачу из учебника не поймет, за что ему поставили минус? Нужно собирать **пятерых участников с 3000+k**, чтобы они смогли объяснить человеку, что домашнюю работу надо делать самостоятельно?

Comment: Перечитайте мой ответ, пожалуйста. Вы исходите из преположений, что использование закрытия уменьшает шанс получения ответа. На практике - наоборот, оно создает вопросам с домашней работой дополнительную бесплатную рекламу. И все, что вы перечислили в качестве плюсов закрытия, срабатывает с точностью до наоборот.

Comment: Авторы вопросов и сейчас не понимают зачастую, за что вопрос закрыт и как его улучшить. Без пояснений конкретных проблем в комментариях закрытие вопросов с этой причиной, как таковое, бесполезно.

Comment: В принципе, закрытие - хорошее решение для добросовестных пользователей, которые действительно пытались решить задачу сами, застряли на каком-то этапе, и не указали в задаче, на каком именно. Но тогда причину нужно очень сильно переформулировать сделав упор именно на что-то вроде "уточните, что именно вызвало у вас затруднения при решении учебной задачи, без этого мы не сможем помочь вам с поиском решения". Мало ли, у участника конкретный шаг вызвал проблемы, а не вся задача целиком.

Comment: На мой взгляд вполне уместно оставить комментарий под вопросом "правилами сайта запрещена домашняя работа, покажите пожалуйста, что конкретно в данном задании вам непонятно" (либо поставить апвоут на уже существующем). Можно поставить [ссылку на правила](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), если есть лишняя минутка, либо оставить на совести топикстартера её поиск. Для большинства будет выглядеть так: семь минусов на вопросе, семь плюсов на комментарии, добавил свой туда и туда, стало по восемь.

Comment: @AK  нужна кнопка с шаблонным коментарием для домашки без закрытия

Comment: @nick_n_a Мммм.. на хешкоде [было такое](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1225/213987), но потом вроде решили, что шаблоны -- это нехорошо и канцелярит.

Answer (score 6):

Я тут еще новичок, но все же... Мне кажется, не стоит убирать эту причину закрытия. На мой взгляд она дает автору вопроса четкое понимание причины закрытия. Минусование вопроса в этом отношении на много менее наглядно. Что касается идеи timob256 с меткой "домашка"... Возможно, это была бы неплохая идея, хотя, подозреваю, большинство ее отправят в игнор

Comment: Зачем нам на сайте школьники двоечники? Они несут 0 ценность сообществу. Хорошо оформленная домашка с попытками решить задачу рука не поднимется закрывать.

Comment: @iluxa1810, вот для двоечников, на мой взгляд, и нужна эта причина закрытия. А метка "домашка" дала бы возможность видеть при просмотре вопросов, что в этом вопросе не стоит искать глубокого профессионализма, зато возможно понадобиться тщательно разжевать ответ.

Comment: Не, ну если для добротной домашки тег, то это норм. Только уж тег не домашка, а "Обучение".

Comment: @iluxa1810, ну, это уже вопрос выбора названия...

Comment: Без пояснений в комментариях ничего эта причина не даёт. Авторы зачастую просто не понимают, что нужно поправить в вопросе.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstansMonica. А что,  если просто заминусовать - лучше поймут ? Я же не пытаюсь сказать, что показать причины всем что-то подскажет.  Но от отсутствия указания причины лучше точно не станет. Вот аргумент Павла о загруженности очередей проверки - значительно более весомый аргумент.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов я чуть позже ответ напишу с моими мыслями. Нет, просто минусовать тоже не совсем правильное решение.

Comment: Проблема в первую очередь в том, что причина кривая. Она подменяет одни понятия другими. Домашка - не всегда плохо, а плохой вопрос - не всегда домашка. Вполне возможно, что нужна другая причина закрытия, но явно не эта. Я постарался расписать,в своём ответе подробнее.

Comment: В текущей формулировка не всякая домашка кривая,  а только та,  которую не пытались решить самостоятельно.  Наверняка ее можно улучшить,  но она не совсем кривая :)

Answer (score 1):

Просто тупо ставить минусы... будут вопросы за что. Да и сам думаешь поймет человек за что или нет...

Достоинство функции "Закрыть", в том, что вниз спускается комментарий. Я считаю что "Закрыть" жмут не сколько для того что б закрыть вопрос, а для того что б шаблонная фраза спустилась вниз - о... Автору вопроса спустилась причина за которую его... Дальше ставим минус.

Вывод, если мы убираем кнопку закрыть с причиной домашка, добавьте пожалуйста мааленькую кнопочку что бы в комментарий скопировало шаблонную согласованую причину типа "Ваш вопрос похож на домашнее задание, в вопросе видно что вы и не пытаетесь разобраться в задании. Такие вопросы на сайте неумесны. Подробнее - ссылка" или что-то такое. Тогда будем знать, нажал минус - метка на удаления есть. Нажал кнопку - малява за что - есть.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то **у нас нет такой причины**, как «*не по теме → учебное задание*». У нас есть «*не по теме → учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос*». То есть домашние задания разрешены, хоть и с ограничениями.

Другое дело, что закрывающие не обращают внимание на вторую часть причины, считая её канцеляритной дополнительной информацией из разряда «не по теме → учебные задания бла-бла-бла». Поэтому я предлагаю сохранить причину, но убрать из формулировки упоминание учёбы, оставив только суть: запрещены требования «вот вам текст задания (не обязательно учебного), думать/искать/узнавать ничего не хочу, напишите мне точный код, и быстро! Хочу только сдать и забыть».

Вернуть прошлый вариант «вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за автора» не получится, так как он вообще не о том. «Завершение» подразумевает, что вопрошающий всё-таки «начал», то есть провёл предварительное исследование и честно сделал какие-то попытки.

Так что придётся составлять новый текст. Однако надо помнить, что:

1. И прошлая, и текущая причины провалились из-за использования слов «задания/задачи», — голосующий делает вывод «задание/задача → учебное задание/учебная задача → д/з под запретом».
2. Среднестатистический голосующий не в курсе официальной позиции по домашним заданиям. Поэтому эта позиция должна быть отражена прямо в причине по аналогии с «ВНИМАНИЕ:» в описании меток, чтобы не было злоупотреблений.
3. У нас осуждают не участников, а поступки. Это сразу отсекает формулировки вида «не по теме → вопрошающий сделал то-то и то-то».

*Если идея взлетит, создам новый вопрос конкретно для приёма вариантов формулировки*.

Comment: *закрывающие не обращают внимание на вторую часть причины ... предлагаю сохранить причину, но убрать из формулировки упоминание учёбы, оставив только суть: запрещены требования «вот вам текст задания (не обязательно учебного), думать/искать/узнавать ничего не хочу, напишите мне точный код, и быстро! Хочу только сдать и забыть».* Всеми лапами "за". Основой, которая идёт в начале фразы, сделать нечто типа "Отсутствует попытка самостоятельно написать программу либо решить проблему, ..." - а дальше хоть про домашку, хоть про что, один фиг половина дальше третьего слова не читает.

Comment: Формулировку уже меняли. Проблема в том, что те, кто рвется именно закрывать, хотят оценивать намерения. Это выстреливает с тем же "посылом на фриланс" например. А с оценкой намерений других людей очень легко ошибиться. Сейчас "учебные задания" - это основной якорь, который хоть как-то сдерживает от применения это причины ко всему подряд, т.к. "учебность" можно более-менее объективно оценить. И именно поэтому вторую часть "никто не читает" - читают, просто прикладывают ее неправильно.

Comment: @Akina такая формулировка - прямой способ закрыть вообще все вопросы без кода. Именно на это наступили в прошлый раз: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5953/177221. Все простые вопросы по технологиям, все базовые "как сделать X" - все под нее попадает :(

Comment: @PashaPash Не... текст про домашку и иже с ею остаётся - просто перемещается в конец. Те, кто оценивает, в отличие от тех, кто спросил, всё-таки знают всю формулировку, а не только её начало (ну или во всяком случае должны и знать, и учитывать при принятии решения).

Comment: @Akina да, я про "не обязательно учебного" - это просто расширяет круг убираемых вопросов на почти все. Вы же не можете проверить, гуглил автор или нет. Решал сам или нет. По крайней мере с "гуглил" - участники массово промахиваются, именно поэтому у нас посылы в гугл запрещены

Comment: Если причину не удалить,а исправить текст, то мы не сможем отличить, что было закрыто со старой причиной, а что с новой. Надо её именно убирать, а при желании добавлять вместо неё новую.

Comment: @Qwertiy вроде бы в аналитике трекается смена текста?

Comment: @PashaPash, вроде нет. В прошлый раз причина убиралась и создавалась новая. Если на dataSE посмотреть id причин, то должны быть разными. Мы конечно можем по дате делить, но это неудобно.

Comment: Взгляни на мой ответ - вроде в чём-то сходится с твоими мыслями // cc @PashaPash

Answer (score 0):

Я могу понять тех, кто хочет убрать метку.

Все мои вопросы, если быть честным, связаны с учебными заданиями и я, как и многие, прихожу сюда за подсказками на тему того, как что-то реализовать в учебных целях.

Тем, кому не нравятся на сайте "просители" готовых решений, к которым отношу и себя, предлагаю пойти в справку и почитать раздел «[Ключевые ценности сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values)» Вырванная из контекста цитата:

> Stack Overflow — это **библиотека готовых решений прикладных задач**, собранных в формате проблема (вопрос) — решения (ответы) в сжатом виде без ненужных деталей. Только «сигнал», никакого «шума».

Но я все же считаю, что тревогу нужно оставить. Ведь нужно отделять халявщиков от тех, кто ищет готовое решение. Я, например, добавляю попытку реализации всегда и, именно потому, что в описании тревоги ясно сказано:

> Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. **Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу**

Если кода нет, а есть только "Помогите сделать то-то и то-то на таком-то языке" и при этом в вопросе нет ни слова, о том, что нужен алгоритм, то я сам пользуюсь этой тревогой.
Именно для того, чтобы отсечь халявщиков, была введена эта метка и со своей задачей она справляется на мой взгляд. Раз пять я ее точно использовал.

Чтобы ей не злоупотребляли, предлагаю дополнить ее описание и разъяснить, в каких случаях стоит ее использовать.

Еще можно ввести механику обязательных меток, как на мете. Например, пусть метка "`помощь в реализации`" отвечает за то, что человек просит помочь в реализации, `алгоритм` — что ему нужен алгоритм решения задачи, а `теория`, за всякие вопросы типа "Как работают циклы в С++?"

А тревогу учебных заданий тогда можно переработать, например, написать:

> Любые вопросы к сообществу допустимы только при условии, что
> вы пытались решить задачу самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.
> Пожалуйста, укажите, что именно вызвало у вас
> трудности при решении задачи. ***Обязательно**, воспользуйтесь меткой "помощь в реализации" м приведите код, который
> вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу, если Ваша проблема связана с вашей попыткой реализации
> (используйте метку "алгоритм" — если Вам нужна помощь с алгоритмом или метку "теория" если у вас возникли трудности с изучением теории какого-либо языка программирования (дополнительно укажите язык))**

Есть еще радикальная идея, что это нужно прописать в справке в разделе вопросы и не публиковать вопросы без кода или метки "алгоритм". Выделять прямо красным и бить тревогу, как это сделано, если не поставить ни одной метки в вопросе.

Следить можно за блоками кода `// код`, ну или за меткой "алгоритм"

Answer (score -3):

Не надо закрывать подобные вопросы (поэтому **такая причина не нужна**).

Оставьте возможность для студентов отвечать на них и набирать таким образом опыт (и репу).

Comment: Поддерживаю. Если вопрос грамотно сформулирован и правильно отформатирован, то это хороший вопрос, что касается и учебных заданий. Мне кажется, основное недовольство вызвано вопросами "пАМАГИТИ я на лабе!1!", которым не место на сайте, но не по причине того, что они учебные, а потому что они не соблюдают никаких правил по оформлению.

Comment: Ага набор репутации.Если вот к такому вопросу прилагается ответ (причем нормальный) , то некоторые его минусуют:   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1036058/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-python-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8c%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%bb/1036071#1036071

Правда за принятый ответ +15, а за минус -2 :)

Answer (score -9):

Если оставить причину, то куча людей, которых обижали в школе, будут закрывать львиную долю нормальных вопросов, а если убрать, то от "домашек" будет не продохнуть.

В этом мире ничто не имеет смысла. В конечном счёте мы все умрём и ruSO умрёт. Я вижу только безысходность.

Answer (score -10):

В таком случае вполне допустим ответ "у меня та же проблема".

Например, "у меня такое же задание, только преподаватель сказал использовать цикл while вместо цикла for". Что делать с таким ответом - пусть создаёт новый вопрос?

Comment: Не понимаю Вас, при чём здесь ответы? Так нужна причина закрытия вопросов "учебные задания" или нет?

Comment: Человек, не способный выполнить задание по информатике, вряд ли станет программистом. Этот сайт явно не для детей.