# Как задать вопрос не по правилам ruSO?

Tags: обсуждение

Как часто меняются правила SO, ruSO? Так что по прецедентам приходиться менять их.

Comment: Давно уже практически не меняются (иногда легкая косметика). А задать вопрос?  Просто берете и задаете, а там будь что будет

Comment: ИМХО, не в ваших силах "продлить жизнь сообщества" и ["оживить этот сайт"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1202900#comment2100053_1202900). Как бы грубо может не звучало, но мы никто и звать нас никак, мы все простые пользователи, которые в праве следить за порядком, заполнять сайт вопросами и помогать с переводом, но поднимать тут активность? Вы серьезно? Это не ваша обязанность, а администрации, они должны внедрять что-то интересное, делать рекламу и т.д., а не вы. Не нравиться то, что имеете, пишите тут, на мете вопросы, предложения, поднимайте дискуссии, но не нарушайте правила.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ кто спорит о статусе, никто ничто. Не в этом суть говорить что человеку не под силу, вы серьезно? Почитайте историю, почитайте законы не говоря уже о правилах. Вы увидите что даже законы меняются, а меняет его общество. Меняет его потому что они не отвечают реалиям. А с моей стороны был задан вопрос думаю понятный. А от вас только комментарии.

Comment: У вас два разных вопроса в названии и в теле. Согласуйте их, пожалуйста.

Comment: После ваших изменений да. Стало не ясно что и по чем. Удалили бы вопрос полностью что так стараться

Comment: А как *"Ну собственно стараюсь как то продлить жизнь сообщества, отвечаю на вопросы, получаю комментарии, ..... Собственно интересует тема."* помогает раскрыть тему вопроса? Никак. Поэтому и просьба к вам - вопрос конркетизировать.

Answer (score 3):

Мета — способ обсудить как общие правила, так и конкретные прецеденты.

Часть правил общая для всех сообществ Stack Exchange, часть устанавливается внутри каждого из сообществ.

Первый шаг — создать вопрос на этой мете с обсуждением либо общей ситуации (желательно с примерами), либо обсудить конкретный прецедент.

[Пример: домашние задания](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9704/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F): длительное обсуждение, тестирование, обсуждение, и т. д.
Часто ли меняются правила? Некоторые — иногда, но не часто. Коренным образом — очень редко.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Интересует как часто меняются правила и когда был последний прецидент.