# Давайте активируем новую страницу публикации вопроса!

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, качество-вопроса, ask-question-wizard

В прошлом году на Stack Overflow на английском было две интересные инициативы. Первая — [помощник публикации вопроса](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/08/22/impact-of-ask-question-wizard/). Цель инициативы была в том, чтобы помочь задающему вопрос сориентироваться и своевременно подсказать, как улучшить итоговый вопрос. Результаты инициативы послужили поводом задуматься о необходимости изменений на странице публикации вопроса в общем. Мы решили [провести исследование](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/26/research-update-improving-the-question-asking-experience/) (та самая вторая инициатива)! Главными вопросами исследования стали:

- Какой опыт у людей, публикующих вопрос на сайте?
- Какая информация необходима людям перед публикацией вопроса?
- Как Stack Overflow вписывается в процессы решения рабочих проблем?

Исследователи смотрели на данные, проводили интервью. Внимание уделяли как количественным, так и качественным показателям. Говорили как с участниками с высокой репутацией, так и с совсем новыми участниками…

#### Результат: новая страница публикации вопроса

[image]

Новая страница — это объединение помощника и стандартной страницы публикации вопроса. Можно полагать, что она поможет задавать вопросы хорошего качества как опытным участникам, так и новичкам.

<sub>([Больше про исследование.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/26/research-update-improving-the-question-asking-experience/))</sub>

Знаете, что самое интересное в этой истории? Новая страница публикации вопроса может быть активирована и на нашем сайте!

#### Что необходимо, чтобы чтобы активировать новую страницу публикации вопроса?

Сейчас нужно лишь немного помощи от заинтересованных участников: хотя новая страница полностью готова для запуска на Stack Overflow на русском, есть одно но — переводы, большинство строк на странице не переведены. Уверен, вы согласитесь, активировать страницу на английском языке на нашем сайте — идея спорная.

#### Как можно помочь?

Мы ищем участников, которые хотят помочь с переводом строк. Индивидуально для них мы активируем новую страницу публикации вопросов раньше остальных, чтобы они могли вживую увидеть строки в интерфейсе пользователя.

Пожалуйста, если вы хотите помочь с переводом строк на новой странице публикации вопроса, напишите мне на почту (nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com) или дайте знать в комментарии к этому вопросу.

Давайте вместе запустим новую страницу, которая, надеюсь, поможет нашим коллегам задавать вопросы исключительно высокого качества! =)

**Обновление**

Создал файл со строками для перевода в csv формате (по всем языкам): http://assets.rudevs.ru/extra/new_ask_question_page.csv

Comment: Судя по всему, дубликат: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9692/15479.

Comment: А как мне предложить вариант перевода?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica На https://ru.traducir.win/

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky как я понимаю, их нужно добавить в спец. группу, т.к, судя по всему, они сейчас [не могут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10088/15479) предлагать переводы.

Comment: У меня добавляются все кроме одной фразы.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica тогда лучше на гитхабе issue создать.

Comment: Предложил несколько переводов два дня назад.
Если они до сих пор не приняты значит их отклонили, или просто надо подождать?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica Строки были не проверены. Проверил, строки будут на сайте в следующей версии движка =)

Comment: Я перевел те строки какие у меня переводятся, остальные [нет](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10088/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4).