# Почему нельзя предложить перевод?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, локализация, traducir

Я залогинился:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но добавить перевод нельзя:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На всех строках? У меня такая ошибка тоже бывает периодически на некоторых строках.

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica Только на этой.

Comment: Через какое-то время должно отпустить.

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica Спасибо!

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica тоже не добавляется, ни в одну строку =(((

Comment: @Denis640Kb вероятно, Николая нужно попросить. Раньше в трансифексе ручками людей добавляли. На счёт традусёра не уверен.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Traducir испанское слово, так что его надо произносить традусир [tra.du.siɾ]/[tra.du.θiɾ].

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica мы с Алексом так прозвали просто, забавно звучит)

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Алекс это A K?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica [αλεχολυτ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/%ce%b1%ce%bb%ce%b5%cf%87%ce%bf%ce%bb%cf%85%cf%84).

Comment: У меня вообще не открывает.

Comment: I've got a repro... the cache headers are wrong, so the browser shows the cached version if you've visited it before. Working on a fix (I _think_ it's because of the headers I'm setting on Cloudflare)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо за репорт!

У меня был настроен заголовок для кэширования, чтобы браузер сохранял содержимое в кэше (из старой версии, когда мы ещё использовали React), но теперь эта фича всё поломала. Что касается ru.traducir.win, у нас используется Cloudflare (т.к. некоторые брандмауэры занесли ip сервера в чёрный список).

Я смог воспроизвести проблему:

1. Войти на ru.traducir.win не авторизованным.
2. Нажать на строку (сохранить URL). Появится сообщение о необходимости входа в систему, как и ожидается.
3. Войти.
4. Открыть страницу по URL с шага 2. Появится сообщение о необходимости авторизации.

Я удалил заголовок для Cloudflare.

Вам необходимо очистить локальный кеш и повторить попытку.

Comment: Thanks for this fix. Typical cache issue :D

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it works ;)

Comment: Не помогло в Chrome.